# Why don't my h1 settings apply to a h1 element inside a <section>

Tags: html, css

I have a h1 in my header and in another section of the document.  I'm told this effects SEO but I digress, i'm just learning by copying other peoples pages and attempting to style them as they did without looking at their code.

So my h1 styles fine but when i target h1 inside a section class the style doesn't apply.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  font-weight: 400px;
  margin: 1px auto 13px;
}

.header h1 {
  border-top: 3px double #232323;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>This is a header</h1>
    <section class="header">
        <h1>This is a header</h1>  
    </section>
</body>
```

My guess is that the class.h1 rule is overriding the h1 rule.  If this is the case, how can I apply my top border to my h1, while still inheriting the h1 properties.

Apologies if I am murdering any CSS nomenclature.

Comment: I'm unclear on which CSS rules aren't being applied which you're expecting to be applied.

Comment: CSS goes by most specific rules. `h1` is less specific than `.photography h1`, so any changes made in the photography style will override the general plain `h1`.

Comment: I want the h1 inside the section to retain the same properties as the global h1, but have a top-border.  For some reason this isn't happening inside my site.

Comment: I think this works as intended, it must be a problem with another part of my code which I didn't include for brevity.  Thank you for confirming that more specific rules inherit properties that are not overridden in said rule. ( I hope I stated that correctly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be much wrong with your code. Indeed if you declare global h1 properties they will be used for all h1's on your site.

If you create specific rules then those will apply to any h1 which meets that rule but the other properties will be inherited (if they are different).

I updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/ukhua6jm/2/

Example:

```
h1 {
   /* global porperties */
   text-align: center;
   font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 1.7em;
   font-weight: 400px;
   margin: 1px auto 13px;
}

.photography h1 {
   border-top: 3px double #232323; /* new property */
   padding-top: 10px;
   font-size: 2em; /* overwrite existing property */
}
```

Comment: Props to @Luis P. A. though for the inherit issue,

Answer (score 5):

The inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value from its parent element. So the parent is section, and there is no rules for font on section. Remove the inherit.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 1px auto 13px;
}

.header h1 {
  border-top: 3px double #232323;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>This is a header</h1>
    <section class="header">
        <h1>This is a header</h1>  
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Also the font-weight should be 400 not 400px.

Answer (score 0):

Use !important on the rules that you want to use to override whatever rules the `<section>` applies to your `<h1>`.

For instance, if you want to apply the fonts on your original `h1` to the one inside the `section`:

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  font-weight: 400px;
  margin: 1px auto 13px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gcj6xLL0/

Comment: Using `!important` generally means you're writing your CSS incorrectly. It's better to learn about how CSS works (cascades) than litter your code with `!important`, it becomes a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: In this case, you're right, since I failed to see that the inherit was to blame. But I tend to disagree on the connotation you're giving to !important, there's some legit uses for it.

Comment: In an emergency maybe.